# Cannot add second domain to Nginx server

Tags: nginx, mac-osx

I have a local macOS server with nginx setup to host one domain: [ogli.codes](https://ogli.codes) (which currently works fine).
Now, I want to add a second domain: `api.ogli.codes`. For now, I'd just like to show a simple hello-world-`index.html` file.

This is my configuration file for *ogli.codes*:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ogli.codes;
    root html/ogli.codes;
    index index.html;
}
```

So I duplicated that file and simply changed the directory and the server name:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.ogli.codes;
    root html/api.ogli.codes;
    index index.html;
}
```

Then, I added the alias to */sites-enabled* and reloaded nginx:

```
sudo nginx -s stop && sudo nginx
```

...and added the folder *api.ogli.codes* in the same directory as *ogli.codes* is in: `/usr/local/var/www/` (yes, this *is* the correct path, as `html` points there directly.
Inside that folder, I created a simple `index.html` file saying *"It works!"*

Now, when I open *ogli.codes* in the browser, it works just fine, but heading over to *api.ogli.codes* gives me a *404 not found*.
So: the domain properly resolves to my server's IP, but I cannot see my site.

What's also interesting is that I tried to support *www.ogli.codes* in the first configuration file, by changing the `server_name` line to:

```
server_name ogli.codes www.ogli.codes;
```

After reloading nginx, I also cannot reach *www.ogli.codes*. Might those issues have the same root?

What's wrong here?

Comment: Check the error log.

Comment: @MichaelHampton this is the only thing I see: `2019/04/03 17:49:43 [notice] 42807#0: signal process started` and `2019/04/03 18:00:50 [error] 42811#0: *15 open() "/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.15.9/html/ogli.codes/robots.txt" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 94.130.167.104, server: ogli.codes, request: "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1", host: "ogli.codes"`

Comment: That means your `root` directive is not pointing to the directory you think it is.

Comment: I just tested changing sth. in the `index.html` for *ogli.codes* (the once that works) and I immediately saw the change on the server when refreshing the page. Note that this only says `robots.txt` is missing, which is true, but shouldn't be related to my question.

Comment: `api.ogli.codes` points to IP `18.191.173.167` while `ogli.codes` → `185.10.148.214`. Probably you should change your DNS

Comment: @AlexeyTen I changed it to another server now where I managed to get this working. If there's any way for me to fix it, I'll change it back to this to 185...  Do you have any idea what I can do?